# Earthing of 2 large metallic plates

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

If we have 2 infinitely large metal plates one of charge $Q$ and another is neutral. They will soon become like this(charges on the 2 surfaces facing each other are opposite in sign, equal in magnitude, it can be proved using Gauss Law. Also, the cornermost faces have equal chare and is equal to the sum of all charges on all plates divided by $2$ ) 
[image]

Now if the neutral plate is earthed, the earth will provide electrons to the neutral plate as the net Potential of that plate is positive due to the left plate. My teacher said that finally, the charges on the plate will be: $0$ on both cornermost surfaces, $Q$ on the right face on unearthed plate, $-Q$ on the left face on earthed plate. I can't understand why this is happening? The distance between both the plates is also not given. In earthing, the potential of earthed plate must be $0$ but here it seems to be positive, because the charge $-Q$ is much closer than $Q$ and the intensity due to any face must be constant and equal to $\frac{Q}{2A \varepsilon_0}$ so, the potential due to $+Q$ will be greater.

Here is the link of the YouTube video I saw: https://youtu.be/bbO2CZp4Oos

Comment: Although it isn't an exact duplicate, there is some discussion of this in my question [Why are the two outer charge densities on a system of parallel charged plates identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466045/why-are-the-two-outer-charge-densities-on-a-system-of-parallel-charged-plates-id)